# ASP.NET MVC paging, when you have multiple criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paging

What would be the best-practice implementation when visualizing a list, driven by multiple criteria, in ASP.NET MVC?

In other words - I am visualizing a very large list of items. Hence - I have already implemented (a generic) paging, which works great. However, I also have an optional search form, which filters the items based on multiple criteria. How would I go about implementing paging, which preserves the search criteria? The obvious answer is with Routing, however, I don't want to pass 10-20 different parameters in the URL. What's my alternative? Form posting?

TL;DR; - Paging with multiple filter criteria, without necessarily creating a Routing for each filter.

Comment: You could store the search criteria in a session/temp data variable.

Comment: A form post sounds like a reasonable idea.  The POST body can contain all the fields for the search/filter/sort/page/etc. or even a complex data structure if needed (probably in JSON).

Comment: Sometimes it's good to pass it as query string so you can catch it or you can share it with others. If that's not your purpose, you could do a POST (conceptually wrong because you should only use POST when you are changing something in the DB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to stay away from routing as that can quickly evolve into an untestable headache. Using POST may not be wise either since it is not very user friendly as they cannot bookmark URLs or use their back button (without reposting) as expected. The best way is to use GET with querystring as you mentioned.

To avoid huge URLs (which shouldn't usually be an issue since URLs generally can go up to 2,000 characters), you can just use default and empty filter values to your advantage. When creating and passing the filter values, just omit the ones that contain default or empty values and implicitly set them in your code. This will rid your URLs of many empty params such as `example.com/?query=somestring&p1=&p2=&p3=&p4=` and reduce it to `example.com/?query=somestring`.

Another random piece of advice, make sure you create a proper ViewModel to contain all the logic pertaining to filter and paging params and their defaults and pass it in as a param in your HttpGet action method.

Comment: I have 'bundled' my parameters in a single object which MVC serializes for me and that's how the URL is generated. However, I can't figure out how to make it omit the properties which are empty, or equal to their default values. Any tips?

Comment: Heres how I did it. If you have a viewmodel to encapsulate all the search params, you can add a property or method within it that returns a Dictionary<string,string> containing the key/value pairs of query string keys and the non-default param values. You can then pass this dictionary as the routevalues param of the ActionLink helper within your view.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering lists based on many and dynamic filters I prefer using oData. Some will say it is a leaky abstraction (which is true) but it really comes in handy in situations like this where you want to be able to return filtered and paged results and where these filters can be complex and could also change over time.

All actual filter generation is then done client side with very minimal server side code. You can expose an IQueryable via the end point with some restrictions on the method like maximum returned results or authorization checks and put the logic and act of building the filter in the client code.

*When looking at the example keep in mind that you do not have to implement the other components like update, delete, create.*

[See this for Web API 2.2 + oData v4.0 example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)